# WinRT dll,desktop app can not load my dll

Tags: dll, windows-runtime, desktop

I got a problem here:
I wrote a win32 dll project,which included WinRT libs; (i used this dll to process windows 10 packages, and it has to be in WinRT environment). and it exports some com-like interfaces (dllregister,dllreg,dllunreg..).

Then ,I wrote a win32 desktop exe,try to load this dll ,but what i got is:
`ErrorCode:126`. So i load this dll by Dependency Walker, and it says that `api-ms-win-core-...dll` can NOT be found.

but why? I can debug this dll in VS2015 with that app,but when i run that app by clicking it,which loads this dll,it returns `errorcode :126`??  (DLL load error??)

Comment: The probable cause is that WinRT dll expects WinRT runtime to be initialized when its `DllMain` is called. I would suggest extracting COM part into a separate dll and use it from both your WinRT dll and desktop application.

Comment: have you build your dll in release mode?